# How to limit ticks on Area Chart within iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm fairly new to designing reports with iReport and I've run into a challenge that I haven't been able to resolve.  I'm trying to graph timestamped data but have it shown as an area graph.  I was successfully able to graph the data using the time series chart, however that format graphs the data as a line.  I need an Area graph.  Therefore I'm attempting to graph that same data using dates as categories.  My problem is that the Area Graph draws every tick mark which results in a clutter look.  I've searched on how to limit ticks but the solutions don't seem to address my problem (or the solution is above my knowledge of java :) ).

So, my question is either:  How can I set a minimum tick on an Area graph?  Or, how can I make a time series chart graph an area instead of a line?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you havent already take a look at the JFreeChart demo [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp) and review XYAreaChartDemo2.java, this example shows a TimeAxis  and and  AreaRenderer :

[image]

If you use the `ChartFactory` try using

```java
  JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart(
    "XY Area Chart Demo 2",
    "Time", "Value",
    dataset,
    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
    true,  // legend
    true,  // tool tips
    false  // URLs
 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Maybe I don't fully understand Jasper reports, but is there a way I can do that with the charts built in with Jasperserver/iReport?